# Why is a parentheses not needed in removeItem? Why must li.onclick = removeItem be inside the newItem() function?

Tags: javascript, html

1. Why do I not need parentheses for removeItem?
2. Why must li.onclick = removeItem be inside the newItem() function?
3. What is the logical sequence when li.onclick event occurs? Is newItem() executed? If so how is it triggered?

I thought that only the enter key will trigger newItem() and since li.onclick = removeItem is inside newItem(), why does clicking trigger it?

Disclaimer: I found this code online but I don't understand these details, hope you guys can help out. Thanks!

html

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

javascript

```
        function newItem() {
            var item = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var ul = document.getElementById("list");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            if (document.getElementById("input").value != ""){
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
                ul.appendChild(li);
                document.getElementById("input").value = "";                
            }
            li.onclick = removeItem;
        }


        document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            newItem();
          }
        }

        function removeItem(e) {
            e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need parentheses because you are storing a reference to the function. The function will be called later. See the following example:

```js
function f1() {
    console.log("f1 called");
}

var function_storage = f1;

function_storage();
```

`li` is declared local to `newItem` so it can only be used inside the function.

When the `onclick` event occurs, the `removeItem` function is called the same way as `f1` in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I not need a parentheses for removeItem?

I assume you mean this line of code:

```
li.onclick = removeItem;
```

Because parentheses would *invoke* the function and assign its *result* to `li.onclick`.  The function doesn't return anything and has no result, and invoking it without providing the event argument it expects would result in an error.

Instead of invoking the function, you're assigning a reference to the function as the `onclick` event handler for the `li` object.  At a later time, if a user clicks on that element, *then* the function will be invoked.

> Why must li.onclick = removeItem be inside the newItem() function?

Well, because that's where the `li` variable is.  You can assign an `onclick` handler anywhere you like, but in order to assign it to a specific object then you need to be in a scope where you have a reference to that object.  Outside of that function there is no `li` variable, so that line of code wouldn't make sense.

> What is the logical sequence when li.onclick event occurs? Is newItem() executed? If so how is it triggered?

Nope, `removeItem()` is executed.  And the browser provides it with a reference to the click event, which will be in the `e` variable inside that function.  This allows you to reference `e.target` to find the element which was clicked.

`removeItem()` is triggered because of the reference assigned to `li.onclick` in the first question above.

Comment: Just to clarify, the onclick handler will be triggered wherever it is placed, but the item must be available in other words if it is a local variable the onclick handler must be placed inside that function?

Comment: @newbie: It doesn't really have anything to do with being an `onclick` handler.  You simply can't use a variable in a scope where it doesn't exist.  The `li` variable is declared and only exists within a specific function in your code, so it can only be used within that function.

Answer (score 1):

1. I found this explanation on Treehouse:

   > Without parentheses you're not actually calling the function. A function name without the parentheses is a reference to the function.
   >
   > We don't use the parentheses in that code because we don't want the function to be called at the point where that code is encountered. Instead, we want to pass a reference to our function into the .focus() method and that method will call our function for us whenever the element receive focus.
2. It doesn't need to be. However, one method of tying events to elements you're creating in JS is tying that event to the element upon creation. Each element will now have that event once inserted into the DOM. Sometimes, this can be wiser. For example, you're going through a for loop creating elements and inserting them into the DOM. Rather than have to loop through again at a later time to add click events, you can just do it there to avoid doing more work.